# Prolog: md5 predicate

Tags: prolog, md5, swi-prolog

I'm trying to write a `md5` predicate that verifies the following:

```
md5("my string", "my md5").
```

A truth instance of such predicate would be

```
md5("long live and prosper", "bf1835ce984d2a97d31409394fe00e9a").
```

I looked into docs, and I found this: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=crypt/2

```
?- phrase("$1$", E, _),
   crypt("My password", E),
   format('~s~n', [E]).
```

anyway, I cannot get it to work. I'm sure I'm missing something as I'm quite new in prolog. Any hint?

***EDIT***

For a better explanation, I assume to create a clause similar to this:

```
md5(P, M):-
   phrase("$1$", E, _),
   crypt(P, E),
   name(M, E),
   format('~s~n', [E]).

?- md5("long live and prosper", "bf1835ce984d2a97d31409394fe00e9a").
   $1$AtnbRJvB$cZ4gZvG2Glelv8hfWztcY/
   false.
```

Thanks

*(Prolog implementation: swi-prolog on Mac OSX El Capitan)*

Comment: Well, my explanation was very poor. I meant I assume that snippet to generate "bf1835ce984d2a97d31409394fe00e9a" from "long live and prosper", but it doesn't (off course, I use my phrase instead of "My password" ). Thanks for notice me, I'll edit my question. Is it clear now?

Comment: @Boris thanks, I updated the question with full input and output from my shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

although deprecated, the functionality you're looking for is [available](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=rdf_db%3Ardf_atom_md5/3)

```
?- use_module(library(semweb/rdf_db)).
true.

?- rdf_atom_md5("long live and prosper", 1, MD5).
MD5 = bf1835ce984d2a97d31409394fe00e9a.
```

Comment: Brilliant! Can you also explain why this works 
   rdf_atom_md5("long live and prosper", 1, 'bf1835ce984d2a97d31409394fe00e9a'). 
while this 
   rdf_atom_md5("long live and prosper", 1, "bf1835ce984d2a97d31409394fe00e9a") 
doesn't?

Comment: It's an asymmetry in parameter handling. Given the name, the predicate would expect an atom as first parameter, and an atom as last parameter, but the type of first one is relaxed to accept several useful representations. The output one is fixed to atom, and doesn't unify with a string.

Answer (score 1):

In SWI-Prolog there is also

> [library(md5): MD5 hashes](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=md5): *Compute MD5 hashes from a Prolog
>   string. This is a rather short-term solution waiting for a more
>   general interface to the libcrypto functions of OpenSSL.*
>
> (a subchapter of this is [md5_hash](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=md5_hash/3)).

This is inside the [SWI-Prolog C-library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/clib.html%27)) and it must be loaded using `use_module(library(md5)).`

... Unfortunately this doesn't work on my Fedora 24. The RPM package `pl-7.2.3-3.fc24.x86_64` seems incomplete. There is no file `/usr/lib64/swipl-7.2.3/library/md5.pl` and indeed:

```
?- use_module(library(md5)).
ERROR: source_sink `library(md5)' does not exist
```

WHY!!

On the other hand, we have module "sha" (`/usr/lib64/swipl-7.2.3/library/sha.pl`). As I just want a hash value, this seems good enough:

> [library(sha): SHA1 and SHA2 Secure Hash Algorithms](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=sha): The library
>   library(sha) provides Secure Hash Algorihms approved by FIPS (Federal
>   Information Processing Standard).

Ok, so:

```
?- use_module(library(sha)).
true.

?- sha_hash("Beyond the Aquila Rift",H,[algorithm(sha256),encoding(utf8)]),hash_atom(H,Hex).
H = [122, 123, 130, 89, 90, 210, 207, 106, 48|...],
Hex = '7a7b82595ad2cf6a30c2ee66672f53e0d630d4c8742d914e73c6761edc9186d2'.

?- sha_hash("Beyond the Aquila Rift",H,[algorithm(sha1),encoding(utf8)]),hash_atom(H,Hex).
H = [7, 152, 27, 81, 140, 122, 225, 76, 238|...],
Hex = '07981b518c7ae14cee70563d87d56db53656232c'.
```

Noice!